# Javascript Video Blob URL and MPEG-Dash

Tags: javascript, php, video, mpeg-dash, dash.js

I am switching our video player over from normal video sources over to chunked progressive video streaming using mpeg-dash. When using mpeg-dash rather than linking to an actual video source you link to a mpeg-dash manifest file which has all the information about each chunk and allows your player to swap in and out chunks as bandwidth changes. Now all of that seems pretty straight forward, however I am also working on setting up blob urls to obscure our source file location and I am running into issues. How does this work since all the documentation I can find on blob responses are either entirely in JS or return an XMLHttpRequest.

You can see an example here within the dash.js documentation that does exactly what I want http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/dash/public/nightly/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html if you inspect the element it has a blob url and loads in chunks but I cannot find any docs on how to do this.

So essentially my question is, how can you get a mpeg-dash manifest file to work in conjunction with the blob url system to obscure source URLs.

Answer (score 3):

> I am also working on setting up blob urls to obscure our source file location

I assure you that you're not usefully obscuring anything.  The data has to come from somewhere.  It's trivial to determine from where no matter how you think you're obscuring it client-side.

Don't bother with this.

> How does this work since all the documentation I can find on blob responses are either entirely in JS or return an XMLHttpRequest.

The reason you see blob with web-based DASH players is that they're using MediaSource Extensions (MSE) to get the data in the first place.  The video player effectively has a blob source which is managed by the browser.  Your JavaScript downloads the chunks and sends them off to the browser to be ran through the codec and output to the video element.

There is a decent MSE example on MDN:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource